# How to draw a line from point to point in C# with Panel, Graphics and Points

Tags: c#, line, panel, point

**Problem**

I have a list of points I desire to draw on a Panel, I have a method to check if the previous point is null, if it is not null then it is supposed to draw a new line from the previous point to the next point. Instead when I click on the button `initialize_shape`, the output I get is a single line connecting two points, the rest of the points are shown but no line exists between them.

**Expectations**

I expected the code to draw a line between each points such that it forms something like a pattern, with each point connected to the next with a line not just a single line.

**Code**

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
 //declare the lists that will hold the points
        List<Point> Shape1 = new List<Point>();
//this method belongs to a button object that draws the shape
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Shape1.Clear();
            Shape2.Clear();
            Point p1a = new Point(20, 30);
            Point p2a = new Point(120,50);
            Point p3a = new Point(160,80);
            Point p4a = new Point(180, 300);
            Point p5a = new Point(100,220);
            Point p6a = new Point(50, 280);
            Point p7a = new Point(20, 140);
            //Hold the Points in an array
            Point[] mypoints = new Point[] {p1a,p2a,p3a,p4a,p5a,p6a,p7a};
            //add the points to the List with one call
            Shape1.AddRange(mypoints);
            //the pens are added here
            Pen pBlue = new Pen(Brushes.Blue, 1);
            Pen pRED = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 1);
            //The panel object used below is a control that was added to the form
            Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
            DisplayShape(Shape1, pBlue, g);
           }
       //This method is supposed to draw lines between the points on the 
       //Panel
         void DisplayShape(List<Point> Shp,Pen pen, Graphics G)
        {
            Point? prevPoint = null;//nullable
            foreach(Point pt in Shp)
            {
                G.DrawEllipse(pen, new Rectangle(pt.X - 2, pt.Y - 2, 4, 4));
                //something in this logic is not right
                if (prevPoint != null)
                {
                    G.DrawLine(pen, (Point)prevPoint, pt);
                    prevPoint = pt;
                }
                G.DrawLine(pen, Shp[0], Shp[Shp.Count - 1]);
            }

        }
  //this method intializes the form
  public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();   
        }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: There may be other problems, but it seems to me that the last `DrawLine()` should be outside the `foreach`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, Thanks trying that out in a little bit

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, placed the `DrawLine()` outside the loop, same problem.

Comment: prevPoint is null to begin with, you only set it to something when its not null. So the code inside `if (prevPoint != null)` is never executed. Try placing `prevPoint = pt;` outside the `if`. Or better yet, use framework method `g.DrawLines(pBlue, mypoints);`

Comment: @Fixation, so what changes should I apply to my code in terms of `prevPoint` being null?

Comment: _Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();_ This is usually a really bad idea as the resulting graphics will not be persistent. Instead draw in the Paint event and use the e.Graphics object there. You could also do non-persistent lines usind g.DrawLins() (plural!) but any minimize/maximize sequence will clear them..

Comment: As for your null.issue: You may choose to copy the points and remove all null oints..

Comment: @TaW, Your `DrawLines()` plural worked and it does not clear on minimize and maximize

Comment: @TaW, No it actually does clear on minimize, it remains on cascade

Comment: Yup. You need to follow the GDI+ grpahics rules: Draw only in/from the Paint event with the e.Graphics param. You will need to store all parameters needed somewhere; also use Invalidate to trigger the Paint when needed, ie whenever the params change!

Comment: @TaW, There is just one problem. I need every point to be connected to each other, after connecting each line, I need the first point connected to the last point.

Comment: **`Point`** is a structure and it will never be `null`. Check against `Point.Empty` maybe instead.

Comment: _the first point connected to the last point_ Then use `DrawPolygon()` !

Comment: @Taw, I want to post about removing outliers from a second image formed by joining a new set of points to align it with the first image, will you help me?

Comment: Guys where can I find a good reference for deriving the partial derives of finding the matrix entries for outlier removal, please

Comment: Am just about to die if i do not figure out how to derive the four equations needed for matrix registration cost

Comment: I need the bounty unlocked on my second related question I posted yesterday, am selling 100 of my reputation for those matrix entries guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code

```
if (prevPoint != null)
{
      G.DrawLine(pen, (Point)prevPoint, pt);
      prevPoint = pt;
}
```

will never run, since prevPoint is only set inside the if-statement. It should be

```
if (prevPoint != null)
{
      G.DrawLine(pen, (Point)prevPoint, pt);
}
prevPoint = pt;
```

or skip the initial point

```
if(Shp.Count < 2) return;
var prevPoint = Shp[0];
foreach(Point pt in Shp.Skip(1)){
    G.DrawLine(pen, prevPoint, pt);
}
```

Also note that:

- `G.DrawLine(pen, Shp[0], Shp[Shp.Count - 1]);` will always draw the same thing, so does not need to be inside the loop
- Drawing inside a button event handler is probably not the way to go, since everything will be cleared when the control is redrawn. I would suggest attaching an event handler to the [paint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.paint?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) event. Or create a subclass of your panel an override `OnPaint`

Comment: This is ingenius, this worked Thank You